# Nagios NRPE check_procs reporting incorrect number

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have an etch nagios server (I will call this NagiosServer), successfully monitoring lots of stuff, including another etch server (MonitorEtch). Using check_nrpe and check_procs I'm able to check the process list for running daemons such as '/usr/sbin/squid'.

Check MonitorEtch from NagiosServer (correct results):

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H MonitorEtch -c check_process -a /usr/sbin/squid 1:1 1:1
PROCS OK: 1 process with args '/usr/sbin/squid'

/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H MonitorEtch -c check_process -a whatever 1:1 1:1
PROCS CRITICAL: 0 processes with args 'whatever'
```

I've built a new server I want to monitor, running Lucid (MonitorLucid). No matter what process I try and monitor from NagiosServer, I get an extra result than I should.

Check MonitorLucid from NagiosServer (incorrect results):

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H MonitorLucid -c check_process -a whatever 1:1 1:1
PROCS OK: 1 process with args 'whatever'

ps ax|grep sophie
12737 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sophie -D
12738 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/sophie -D
19591 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto sophie

/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.19.252 -c check_process -a sophie 1:1 1:1
PROCS CRITICAL: 3 processes with args 'sophie'
```

Contents of /etc/nagios/nrpe_local.cfg on MonitorLucid/MonitorEtch:

```
allowed_hosts=NagiosServer,127.0.0.1
dont_blame_nrpe=1
command[check_process]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -a $ARG1$ -m PROCS -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$
```

Yet if I perform the check locally, it returns the correct results!

Check MonitorLucid from MonitorLucid (correct results):

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -a whatever -m PROCS -w 1:1 -c 1:1
PROCS CRITICAL: 0 processes with args 'whatever'

/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -a sophie -m PROCS -w 1:1 -c 1:1
PROCS CRITICAL: 2 processes with args 'sophie'
```

I'm out of ideas at this point, short of checking for 1 more instance than I should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem. `check_procs` is internally calling `/bin/ps axwo 'stat uid pid ppid vsz rss pcpu comm args'`, it's listing the processes and then counting them. If you have configured nagios to run with a different user, it's using `sudo` to execute the command. And here is the problem. If you type `sudo ps -AF | grep sudo`, some distribution return "`grep sudo`", others return "`sudo ps -AF`" and "`grep sudo`". As check_procs is counting all processes, you will get different results on different machines. Unfortunately I do not have a solution yet how to force check_procs to not count `sudo` processes.

Comment: No need to use `sudo` with `check_procs` plugin. You can write your own simple plugin to check if a process is running, for e.g: `ps -ef | grep sud[o] | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the version of `check_procs` in Lucid is buggy (or at least has changed it's behaviour); the fact that it's always finding one extra suggests that it's doing a substring match on any part of the process name and arguments and finding one of the processes associated with running the plugin.  Worth reporting a bug to Ubuntu about it.